# toc-like forward storage for captions

Tags: tables, hyperref, auxiliary-files

Dear experts: how does one write out the table captions for use later? Think

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mycaption}[2]{\caption{#2}\label{#1}\savecaptioncontent{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\insertmytable}[1]{
  \begin{center}
   Insert Table~\ref{#1} here: '\contentcaption{#1}'
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

blah blah.  Table~\ref{tbl:first} tells me little.

\insertmytable{tbl:first}

above, it should have printed:

\begin{center}
   Insert Table~\ref{tbl:first} here: 'This is my first table'
\end{center}

\begin{table}
\mycaption{tbl:first}{This is my first table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Almost surely I want to write to the `.aux` file, but my amateurish attempts are stuck in expansion hell. In fact, there may be an even easier solution for this special case: I think the `.aux` file already saves captions with a `\newlabel` when `hyperref` is used (when is it not?), but I would need to pick off the third parenthesized expression from the aux-written `\newlabel`.  Instead of guessing further, I hope this is a common enough issue that it is easy and becomes a good sx answer...

help appreciated.  /iaw

Comment: Using `\caption{#2}` all the time will drop the short caption text property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 'dirty' trick: Write `\newlabel` explicitly to the `.aux` file with a prefix for a new label, say `stored::` and use `\nameref*` from `hyperref` to get the label content.

The `{}{}` and `{}` arguments can be empty here, as they are not important for this approach.

However, expansion will be an issue. If the caption content itself holds commands that are quite simple, `\unexpanded{}` should be used. A better solution depends on the precise requirements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\savecaptioncontent}[2]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{stored::#1}{{}{}{\unexpanded{#2}}{}}%
  }
}
\newcommand{\contentcaption}[1]{%
  \nameref*{stored::#1}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mycaption}[2]{\caption{#2}\label{#1}\savecaptioncontent{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\insertmytable}[1]{
  \begin{center}
   Insert Table~\ref{#1} here: '\contentcaption{#1}'
 \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

blah blah.  Table~\ref{tbl:first} tells me little.

But now:
\insertmytable{tbl:first}

above, it should have printed:

\begin{center}
   Insert Table~\ref{tbl:first} here: 'This is my first table'
\end{center}

\begin{table}
\mycaption{tbl:first}{This is my first table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]